# camel-kafka consumer : header values of non-String datatype are null

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-camel

Non-String kafka-message headers are always null.
Message headers of type String datatype are extracted correctly.

```
package com.test.KafkaSimpleProject;

import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.Message;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        try {
            context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
                @Override
                public void configure() throws Exception {

                    //producer route
                    from("timer:foo?period=3000&repeatCount=1000&delay=3000")
                        .setBody()
                        .constant("This is kafka message")
                        .setHeader("name")
                        .simple("ApacheCamelkafka", String.class)
                        .setHeader("contact")
                        .simple("123123", Integer.class)
                        .setHeader("trueFalse")
                        .simple("false", Boolean.class)
                        .to("kafka:test?brokers=localhost:9092");

                    //Consumer route
                    from("kafka:test?brokers=localhost:9092")
                        .process(new org.apache.camel.Processor() {
                            public void process(org.apache.camel.Exchange exchange)
                            throws Exception {

                                Message in = exchange.getIn();
                                String name = in .getHeader("name", String.class);
                                Integer contact = in .getHeader("contact", Integer.class);
                                Boolean trueFalse = in .getHeader("trueFalse", Boolean.class);
                                System.out.println("Name:" + name);
                                System.out.println("contact:" + contact);
                                System.out.println("trueFalse:" + trueFalse);

                            }
                        });
                }
            });
            context.start();
            Thread.sleep(20000000);
        } finally {
            context.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Expected output:

Name: ApacheCamelkafka

contact: 123123

trueFalse: false

Actual output:

Name: ApacheCamelkafka

contact: null

trueFalse: null

Comment: Surprisingly it's working with "direct" component but not working with "kafka"